# APIM : Subscriptions required only 1 operation in under same API where other Operation does not required

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I have Scenario under APIM policy where I have a API but few Operation required **Subscriptions-Key** but few does not required so under one API both the option is possible?

In the below screenshot only **GetStations **Operation required **Subscriptions-Key** other not?

[image]

I want to know is it possible or it's limitation from AZURE side.

Answer (score 0):

APIM does not support operation-level subscriptions. Use other authentication methods which you can apply through policies on the operation level, like [client certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients) or possibly use [JWT tokens validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy).